# Limit the possible values for an attribute in a Python Class

Tags: python, class, attributes

I'm trying to build a class in python describing a wheel position
I want it to be limited to 4 values `("FL", "FR", "RL", "RR")`

But now when I try to create a class for the WheelPos attribute and limit its values, both using `Enum` and `__slots__`, this doesn't prevent me from choosing any value I like for the attribute.

Is there an instrument in python to say the attribute values to stick within a finite list?

```py
from operator import attrgetter

class WheelPos():
    __slots__ = ("FL", "FR", "RL", "RR")

class wheel(object):
    def __init__(self, WheelPos, pressure):
        self.WheelPos = WheelPos
        self.pressure = pressure

class car(object):
    wheel1 = wheel(1,3)
    wheel2 = wheel("front_left",3)
    wheel3 = wheel("RL",3)
    wheel4 = wheel("RR",3) 

    wheels = [wheel1, wheel2, wheel3, wheel4]
  
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

```
macchina = car("micra")
print(macchina.wheel1.WheelPos)
print(macchina.wheel2.WheelPos)
print(macchina.wheel3.WheelPos)
```

```
out: 1, front_left, RL
```

Comment: This does not really match the spirit of Python as a dynamically typed scripting language. Restrictions for attribute values are not usually necessary. Nevertheless, it might be possible to use properties with setter and getter methods, where you can prohibit any values you don't want to allow.

Comment: I think you're right. But this excercise was proposed to me during an interview and as I couldn't completely answer during the process, I just tried to complete it myself at home,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved the issue by myself in the meanwhile, so I'm posting the answer in case it could help anyone in the future.

I limited the WheelPos attribute values describing it as an Enum object and then introducing a "control function" which check if the init function for any wheel object is within the enum values

```
from enum import Enum
    
class wheel(object):
    class WheelPos(Enum):
        FL = "FL"
        FR = "FR"
        RL = "RL"
        RR = "RR"
    
    def __init__(self, WheelPos, pressure):
        self._set_WheelPos(WheelPos)
        self.pressure = pressure

    def _set_WheelPos(self, WheelPos):
        if WheelPos in set(item.value for item in self.WheelPos):
            self.WheelPos = WheelPos
        else:
            raise ValueError("Wheel Position value not valid")

class car(object):
    wheel1 = wheel("FL",3)
    wheel2 = wheel("FR",3)
    wheel3 = wheel("RL",3)
    wheel4 = wheel("RR",3) 

    wheels = [wheel1, wheel2, wheel3, wheel4]
  
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Hence even out of the car class definition I am assured only "right" values for the wheel attributes can be called

Comment: Thanks for the post, the attrgetter import isn't being used here

Comment: Edited it out. Probably had forgot it there from an older version of the code.
Thanks for the note.